# get the row data using jquery by clicking buttons for that row

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am having issues to get the table data in the row if a button is selected. I have two buttons approve and deny and based on what button user clicks I want to grab the data using query. can get the row numbers and stuff just not the row data. I need to get the id and tester.

here is what I have

```
<table id="mytable" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Tester</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Approve</th>
<th>Deny</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="test">
<td class="ids">11565 </td>
<td class="tester">james</td>
<td>2012-07-02 </td>
<td><Button id="Approved" type="submit" >Approved</button>
</td>
<td><Button id="deny_0" type="submit" >Denied</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

here is my javascript to get the tr and td number but I am not sure how to use it to get what I need

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    /*$('#cardsData .giftcardaccount_id').each(function(){

        alert($(this).html());
     }); */
    $('td').click(function(){
          var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
          var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
          alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
         // alert($tds.eq(0).text());
          console.log($("tr:eq(1)"));
         // $("td:eq(0)", this).text(),

        });


});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Approved').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().siblings('.ids').text();
        var tester = $(this).parent().siblings('.tester').text();

        console.log(id);
        console.log(tester);
    });
});​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXyrZ/3/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var id = tr.find('.ids').text();
        var tester = tr.find('.tester').text();
        alert('id: '+id+', tester: ' + tester);
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mM47s/)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `closest()` to get the `tr` and then descend from there.

```
var tr = $('td').closest('tr')
```

Also I think this is unnecessary, in your example that would be `$(this)`:

```
$(this).parent().children().index($(this)) // === $(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table').on('click', 'button', function() {
      var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
      var id = $('td.ids', parentRow).text();
      var tester = $('td.tester', parentRow).text();

    alert('id: ' + id + ', tester: ' + tester);
});​
```